# Alternating Post Styles on Homepage

Tags: posts

I am trying to create alternating post styles for the homepage but can't seem to work it out.

I'd like to have full width image, followed by feature image left- post title right, then feature image right - post title left and back to the beginning again. Here are two examples similar to what I am hoping to do.
http://www.loveshopshare.com/
http://shinebythree.com/

I am working off WooThemes Canvas. Also have Divi but it seems Canvas offers more control.

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom classes to each post.  Here is a quick example of one approach:

```
add_action('post_class','YOURNAME_post_class');

function YOURNAME_post_class( $classes ) {

    global $wp_query;

    if( ! $wp_query->is_main_query() )
        return $classes;

    $classes[] = 'class-on-all-posts';
    if( 0 == $wp_query->current_post || 0 == $wp_query->current_post % 3 )
        $classes[] = 'class-on-every-third-post';
    if( 0 == $wp_query->current_post || 0 == $wp_query->current_post % 2 )
        $classes[] = 'class-on-every-second-post';
    return $classes;


}
```

You can then tweak the image and div alignment css based on the post classes.